# C# how to generate a proper error quickly for testing purposes

Tags: c#

I have some code in my error handler I need to test against a realistic error. How can I generate an error that has a full stack trace and is just as realistic as a runtime error.

I am using a general catch on an exception. So do not need a specific type of exception in this particular case.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
object m = null;
string s = m.ToString();
```

Instant `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: :( Beaten to it by 15 seconds!

Comment: Hahaha, you added an introduction ;)

Comment: Note to self: just type any old rubbish and hit 'Answer' ;)

Comment: Why not just 'throw new NullReferenceException("For testing purposes");' ?

Comment: Why, why not, it doesn't really matter. This wasn't a question of design, it was a question of a quick test.

Comment: because throw is not allowed in try block

Answer (score 29):

What about

```
throw new Exception("this is a test");
```

Answer (score 11):

You can throw any kind of .Net exception by calling

```
throw new OutOfMemoryException();
throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

The exception names can be any dotnet exceptions. you can even create and throw your own specific exceptions.

To get a list of the CLR exceptions, in VS click on the debug menu and then the exceptions menu.

Answer (score 7):

One DivideByZeroException coming up!:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1 / i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a null reference exception... or a division by zero exception.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try using a mocking framework, e.g. Moq, and Rhino Mocks and then pass in the associated Exception you are hoping to catch.

Answer (score -1):

```
throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -2):

how about the good old division by zero?

5 / 0

Comment: The compiler prevents this, so this will never become a runtime exception.